# next and rest in clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am reading explanations on **rest** vs **next** in clojure.
As I understand it, it breaks down to `next` evaluating/realizing the tail of the sequence,
to know wether it should return `nil` or not, while `rest` always returns sequence, so it is lazier.

However, what I dont understand is this: both functions need to know wether there is something
in the tail. One will return `nil` if there is nothing left, other one will return `()`.

So basicaly, they both need to check/evaluate what is left.
Cause even `rest`, to return `()`, needs to know that it wont return say `(2)` for example.

So even `rest` needs to do evaluation.

But explanations say the opposite.
That only `next` does that evaluation, but `rest` does not, therefore is lazier.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
user> (def test-seq (lazy-cat [1] [(do (print "Hi!") 2)]))
#'user/test-seq
user> (def rest-test (rest test-seq))
#'user/rest-test
user> (def next-test (next test-seq))
Hi!
#'user/next-test
```

If `rest` needed to evaluate an element, you would have seen "Hi!" get printed after I called `(rest test-seq)`. Clearly, `rest` does not need to do evaluation in order to work.

The reason is that `rest` does not return () or (2) or anything like that; it returns an unevaluated lazy sequence every time it is called, and the question of whether or not there is anything to return is only answered when that sequence is evaluated later.

Comment: I think I got it. Clojure is actually amazingly simple.